# SkypeForBusiness.framework addPersistentStoreWithType method of NSPersistentStoreCoordinator returning nil in iOS 10

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, skype-for-business

I am using SkypeForBusiness.framework for my App, now after updating my ipad 4 to iOS 10 the addPersistentStoreWithType method of NSPersistentStoreCoordinator returning **nil** when i run the same code on my ipad 3 with iOS 9.3.5 it returning a object

```
- (NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *)persistentStoreCoordinator {

static NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *coordinator = nil;
static dispatch_once_t token;
dispatch_once(&token, ^{

    // get the model
    NSManagedObjectModel *model = [NSManagedObjectModel mergedModelFromBundles:nil];

    // get the coordinator
    coordinator = [[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator alloc] initWithManagedObjectModel:model];

    // add store
    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    NSURL *applicationSupportURL = [[fileManager URLsForDirectory:NSLibraryDirectory inDomains:NSUserDomainMask] lastObject];
    [fileManager createDirectoryAtURL:applicationSupportURL withIntermediateDirectories:NO attributes:nil error:nil];
    NSURL *databaseURL = [applicationSupportURL URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"database_name.sqlite"];
    NSError *error = nil;

    //        [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtURL:databaseURL error:&error];

    NSDictionary *options = @{
                              EncryptedStorePassphraseKey : @"********",
                              //            EncryptedStoreDatabaseLocation : databaseURL,
                              NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption : @YES,
                              NSInferMappingModelAutomaticallyOption : @YES
                              };
    NSPersistentStore *store = [coordinator
                                addPersistentStoreWithType:EncryptedStoreType
                                configuration:nil
                                URL:databaseURL
                                options:options
                                error:&error];
    //        coordinator = [EncryptedStore makeStoreWithOptions:options managedObjectModel:model];

    NSAssert(store, @"Unable to add persistent store!\n%@", error);

});
return coordinator;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the fix to the problem

Previous Xcode's like xcode 6&7 used to throw error something like this

> “_sqlite3_key” Symbol(s) not found for architecture i386

Now in Xcode 8

> *** Assertion failure in -[AppDelegate persistentStoreCoordinator], /Users/prosares/Desktop/MyProject/MyApp/AppDelegate.m:198
>
> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Unable to add persistent store!
>   (null)'

Xcode 8 throws unrelated errors, @Apple should solve this type of bugs it is very annoying, i used to do this in Xcode 7 that is why i thought of giving it a try and it worked

Xcode 8 also prints unwanted logs when we run App in Simulator, which makes debugging difficult

below is the link in which i already answered for this problem

[click here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39597308/6256965)